Inverting Phonon Creation / Annihilation Operators for General 3D Lattice
My lecture notes, which cite textbooks by Ashcroft/Mermin and Cohen/Louie as sources, give the following definitions for the creation and annihilation operators for phonons in a 3D lattice, with multiple atoms per unit cell:
\begin{equation}
    b_{\textbf{q},\nu} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}
    \sum_{\textbf{R},\alpha,n} e^{-i \textbf{q} \cdot \textbf{R}} \
    \eta^{\alpha,n}_{\textbf{q},\nu} \
    \bigg[ \
    \sqrt{ \frac{m_{\alpha} \omega_{\textbf{q},\nu}}{2 \hbar} } \ u^{\alpha,n}_{\textbf{R}}
    + i \sqrt{ \frac{1}{2 \hbar m_{\alpha} \omega_{\textbf{q},\nu}} } \ p^{\alpha,n}_{\textbf{R}}
    \ \bigg]
\label{ph_annihilation_op}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    b^{\dagger}_{\textbf{q},\nu} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}
    \sum_{\textbf{R},\alpha,n} e^{i \textbf{q} \cdot \textbf{R}} \
    \overline{ \eta^{\alpha,n}_{\textbf{q},\nu} } \
    \bigg[ \
    \sqrt{ \frac{m_{\alpha} \omega_{\textbf{q},\nu}}{2 \hbar} } \ u^{\alpha,n}_{\textbf{R}}
    - i \sqrt{ \frac{1}{2 \hbar m_{\alpha} \omega_{\textbf{q},\nu}} } \ p^{\alpha,n}_{\textbf{R}}
    \ \bigg]
\label{ph_creation_op}
\end{equation}
Where $\textbf{R}$ denotes a lattice vector, $\alpha$ indexes atoms and $n$ runs over the Cartesian directions. $u^{\alpha,n}_{\textbf{R}}$ and $p^{\alpha,n}_{\textbf{R}}$ are, respectively, the position and momentum operators for atom $\alpha$ in cell $\textbf{R}$ along the Cartesian direction $n$. $N$ is the total number of unit cells in the crystal. $\eta^{\alpha,n}_{\textbf{q},\nu}$ is the component of the phonon eigenvector for mode $(\textbf{q},\nu)$ in direction $n$ for atom $\alpha$.
Using these definitions, I can verify by hand that the standard bosonic commutation relations are satisfied:
\begin{equation}
    \big[ b_{\textbf{q},\nu} \ , \ b^{\dagger}_{\textbf{q'},\zeta} \big]
    = \delta_{\textbf{q},\textbf{q'}} \ \delta_{\nu,\zeta}
\label{ph_ops_commutation_relation}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \big[ b_{\textbf{q},\nu} \ , \ b_{\textbf{q'},\zeta} \big] = 0
\label{double_annihilation_comm}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \big[ b^{\dagger}_{\textbf{q},\nu} \ , \ b^{\dagger}_{\textbf{q'},\zeta} \big] = 0
\label{double_creation_comm}
\end{equation}
It is then stated that these relations can be inverted to give the following for the position operator for atom $\alpha$ in cell $\textbf{R}$ along the Cartesian direction $n$:
\begin{equation}
    u^{\alpha,n}_{\textbf{R}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}
    \sum_{\textbf{q},\nu} e^{i \textbf{q} \cdot \textbf{R}} \
    \eta^{\alpha,n}_{\textbf{q},\nu} \
    \sqrt{ \frac{\hbar}{2 m_{\alpha} \omega_{\textbf{q},\nu}} } \
    \big( b_{\textbf{q},\nu} + b^{\dagger}_{-\textbf{q},\nu} \big)
\label{posn_op}
\end{equation}
However, if I plug the definitions of $b_{\textbf{q},\nu}$ and $b^{\dagger}_{\textbf{q},\nu}$ directly into this expression, I get:
\begin{equation}
    u^{\alpha,n}_{\textbf{R}} = \frac{1}{N}
    \sum_{\textbf{q},\nu} e^{i \textbf{q} \cdot \textbf{R}} \
    \eta^{\alpha,n}_{\textbf{q},\nu} \
    \sqrt{ \frac{\hbar}{2 m_{\alpha} \omega_{\textbf{q},\nu}} } \
    \sum_{\textbf{R'},\beta,m} e^{-i \textbf{q} \cdot \textbf{R'}} \
    \eta^{\beta,m}_{\textbf{q},\nu} \\
    \times \bigg[ \
    \sqrt{ \frac{m_{\beta} \omega_{\textbf{q},\nu}}{2 \hbar} } \ u^{\beta,m}_{\textbf{R'}}
    + i \sqrt{ \frac{1}{2 \hbar m_{\beta} \omega_{\textbf{q},\nu}} } \ p^{\beta,m}_{\textbf{R'}}
+
    \sqrt{ \frac{m_{\beta} \omega_{\textbf{q},\nu}}{2 \hbar} } \ u^{\beta,m}_{\textbf{R'}}
    - i \sqrt{ \frac{1}{2 \hbar m_{\beta} \omega_{\textbf{q},\nu}} } \ p^{\beta,m}_{\textbf{R'}}
    \ \bigg]
\end{equation}
The momentum operators cancel, and simplifying a bit:
\begin{equation}
    u^{\alpha,n}_{\textbf{R}} = \frac{1}{N}
    \sum_{\textbf{q},\nu} \
\sum_{\textbf{R'},\beta,m} \sqrt{ \frac{m_{\beta}}{m_{\alpha}} } \
e^{i \textbf{q} \cdot (\textbf{R} - \textbf{R'})} \
    \eta^{\alpha,n}_{\textbf{q},\nu} \
    \eta^{\beta,m}_{\textbf{q},\nu} \
    \ u^{\beta,m}_{\textbf{R'}}
\end{equation}
Now, supposedly, we can use the following sum rule identities for the phonon eigenvectors to get the final expression:
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{\textbf{q},\nu} \
    \eta^{\alpha,i}_{\textbf{q},\nu} \
    \overline{\eta^{\beta,j}_{\textbf{q},\nu}} \
    = N \ \delta_{i,j} \ \delta_{\alpha,\beta}
\label{phonon_eigenvector_identity_q_nu_sum}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{\alpha,i} \
    \eta^{\alpha,i}_{\textbf{q},\nu} \
    \overline{\eta^{\alpha,i}_{\textbf{q'},\zeta}} \
    = \delta_{\textbf{q},\textbf{q'}} \ \delta_{\nu,\zeta}
\label{phonon_eigenvector_identity_alpha_i_sum}
\end{equation}
I can verify by hand that these identities hold true. However, they cannot be readily applied here because of the presence of the exponential $e^{i \textbf{q} \cdot (\textbf{R} - \textbf{R'})}$ in the sum. If this term were replaced with a Kronecker-Delta $\delta_{\textbf{R},\textbf{R'}}$, then the expression would correctly reduce to just $u^{\alpha,n}_{\textbf{R}}$, as desired. However, we cannot carry out the sum over $\textbf{q}$ to get $\delta_{\textbf{R},\textbf{R'}}$ because of the attached $\eta^{\alpha,n}_{\textbf{q},\nu}$ and $\eta^{\beta,m}_{\textbf{q},\nu}$ factors.
What is going wrong here? Other questions I have seen on this site seem to only cover the 1D case, or the case of a single atom per unit cell.

Which textbook (title, author, edition, chapter, page and equation numbers)?

@TobiasFünke Thanks for your response. These are actually from my condensed matter lecture notes, which cite textbooks by Ashcroft/Mermin and Cohen/Louie as sources (but give no particular chapter or page number). I have clarified this in the original post.

Hi. Can you perhaps link to the lecture notes if possible? Anyway, have you consulted the cited sources and check what they do/derive?

Unfortunately the lecture notes are copyrighted and require a university login. I have looked at the cited textbooks, and they cover either only the one-dimensional case, or the 3D case but with only a monatomic lattice, and even in the latter case several intermediate lines of working are skipped when going from the definitions of the $b_{\textbf{q},\nu}$ and $b^{\dagger}{\textbf{q},\nu}$ to inverting them to get $u^{\alpha,n}{\textbf{R}}$ (it is simply stated to use the Kronecker Delta identities detailed in my post). Following my working, can you see specifically where I've gone wrong?

The phonon eigenvectors can be made orthonormal with respect to the internal degrees of freedom in a unit cell:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\nu} \eta_{\mathbf q, \nu}^{\alpha, n} \,\left( \eta_{\mathbf q, \nu}^{\beta, m} \right)^* = \delta_{\alpha\beta}\delta_{nm} \quad \forall\mathbf q\in BZ
\end{equation}
The result follows.
